# small-caps latin characters on PDF

Tags: css, pdf, utf-8, fonts, mpdf

I generate a PDF using mPDF Library.

I use *Open Sans* font, the content has latin characters such as **ä**

It shows correctly if it is plain **ä**,

But the problem is if I added a `font-variant: small-caps;` to this text. It becomes like this:

[image]

I tested if there is just a problem in upper-case of **ä**:

[image]

But there is not. If you try to select and copy the word with the "box" **ä** (I mean the first image).. then paste it some where. You will have the correct **nationalität**.

So the question is, What is the problem there? Is it on the *font*? In a *PDF*? In a *CSS*? Or in a *encoding*(Currently, It is utf-8)?

**How can I fix it?**

I know that I can just use something like:

```
<span class="bigger-font">N</span><span class="smaller-font">ATIONALITÄT</span>
```

Then I will get my desired results. But I really want to use `font-variant: small-caps;` because this is easier.

Answer (score 2):

**I fixed it.**

I don't know the specific technical explanation to this,

But after a lot of trial and errors, trouble shooting... I found out the solution to the problem. I just added a list of *uppercase* latin characters at the mark-up so the PDF already have rendered *uppercase* latin characters to use in `font-variant: small-caps;`

```
<span style="visibility: hidden; font-family: open_sans;">
    ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÑÇÆ <!-- pre render it. small-caps may use them later. -->
</span>
<font>
    Nationalität <!-- It will now rendered correctly. -->
</font>
```

Because it seems like, that `font-variant: small-caps;` applied at the last proccess of generating the PDF and it cannot get *uppercase* latin characters from the Font family.

I can't solidly explain and prove the cause of the problem. I don't know the technical reason. If some of you have a knowledge about it. Please let us know.

Comment: It looks like a bug in mPDF, You could try the latest version of mPDF and/or report this as an [mPDF issue](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues)